# ¿Qué trae este fragmento de código? ' lleno = tope>=buff.length; '

Tags: java

Estoy viendo un ejemplo de hilos

```
  public synchronized void poner(char c) throws Exception{
        while(lleno){
            wait();
        }
        buff[++tope] = c;
        vacio = false;
        lleno = tope>=buff.length;
        notifyAll();
    }
```

¿mi duda es, qué pasa aquí? :

```
lleno = tope>=buff.length;
```

estas variables están inicializadas así:

```
    private int tope = 0;
    public boolean lleno = false;
```

¿Qué está pasando aquí? ¿Qué está asignando a la variable?

Comment: Reconozco no haber visto nunca ese tipo de uso, pero al ver que `lleno` es booleana, debería asignar a dicha variable el resultado de la comparación: `tope>=buff.length;` Es decir, si `tope` es igual o mayor que `buff.length` asignará el valor `true` a `lleno`, de lo contrario le asignará `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pregunta me pareció curiosa. Y reconozco no haber visto nunca código escrito así.

Tenemos que tomar en cuenta lo siguiente:

- `lleno` es una variable de tipo booleana (verdadero/falso)
- `>=` es un operador de comparación.
- `length` calcula el tamaño de un array (en el ejemplo, para simplificar he tomado una cadena y calculado su tamaño con el método `lenght()`

Entonces la línea:

```
lleno = tope>=buff.length;
```

Hace una comparación y asigna directamente a la variable `lleno` el resultado (`true` o `false`)  de esa comparación.

Hice este código de prueba para confirmarlo:

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/XQL32500)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    private static int tope = 0;
    public static boolean lleno = false;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         String buff="Ok";
         lleno = tope>=buff.length();
         System.out.println(lleno);

         buff="";
         lleno = tope>=buff.length();
         System.out.println(lleno);        
    }
}
```

#### `Resultado`

```
false
true
```

Comment: Ya voy comprendiendo el qué se hizo. Yo tampoco había visto un código así, y se me hizo raro, no lograba comprender qué pasaba.

Answer (score 0):

La variable "lleno" recibe el valor que genera la condicion "tope>=buff.length"

Si dicha condicion da true, lleno recibe true, si la condicion da false, la variable lleno <- recibira false.